# How to set default String from native ios app to facebook page from iphone app using dialog

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

below is my code

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"MyTestAPP", @"name",
                               @"http://myserver.com/", @"link",
                               @"My Post!", @"caption",
                               @"ValuedCommunity", @"description",
                               myMessage, @"message",              
                               nil];


// Publish.

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Now with this code when I click on publish button I get this
[image]

I have tried graph api using the below code but it gave me an error msg of "***facebookerrdomain error 10000***".
**[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST"     andDelegate:self];**
Now What I want to do is, want to set "myMessage" text instead of Say Something about this.
Is it possible to do so??
If yes then how can I achieve it. 
Please Advice
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible. Use `requestWithGraphPath:andParams:andHttpMethod:andDelegate:` method and set permission as `publish_stream`, then you will get message.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   yourMessage,@"message",nil];

    NSString *user_selected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/feed"];    
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:user_selected andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks Prasad for response. But the thing is, I have already tried it and it didn't work I have mentioned it in my post.

Comment: Check facebook is null or not and also permessions?

Comment: When I use the graph API it is giving me this error **"an active access token must be used to query information about the current user"**

Answer (score 0):

Hi Every1 I was Trying to solve this from past 2 days And How I solved 
add One more parameter named access_token in NSMutableDictionary's param object like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Ahha", @"name",
                               @"http://vctestserver.com/", @"link",
                               @"VCAHHA", @"caption",
                               @"ValuedCommunity", @"description",
                               storyTwtFB, @"message", 
                               accessToken,@"access_token",
                               nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Where  I got **accessToken's** Value from delegate mathod [facebook accessToken]. and storyTwtb is my application's String that I wanted to post on facebook.